# replace regex value in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

1. From the below line:
   **[1;32mget[0m  /dir/dir/dir    {}  [oiid:197,uiid:7522]    [32m200[0m  (676ms)**
2. convert it to:
   **get   /dir/dir/dir    {}  [oiid:197,uiid:7522]    200 (676ms)**
3. any suggestions on regex please the value *200* can be any number and the value *get* can be any http method.
4. I have tried

````
            $_.replace("[[\d+m]","").replace('[[1;\d+m]',"").replace('[[\d+]m]',"")
         } | Set-Content $newfilepath```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using `-replace` operator and a regex:

```
$string = '[1;32mget[0m /dir/dir/dir {} [oiid:197,uiid:7522] [32m200[0m (676ms)'
$string -replace '\[\d.*?m'
```

`\[` matches `[` and note that it needs to be escaped for literal match because `[` is special to regex. `\d` is a digit. `.*?` matches as few characters as possible until `m` is matched.

The String class `Replace()` method does not support regex. So you cannot use regex expressions like `\d` inside.